# What is the best hypothesis test method for a small sample size?

Tags: time-series, sample-size, small-sample

i am somewhat confused on how to proceed with the hypothesis testing, i have 1 sample with a total of 31 inputs divided into 2 groups of different conditions, 1 sample has 16 inputs, the other has 15. when i tried using simple t-test for each groups, my mentor told me that  using t-test on a sample with less than 30 data would cause a statistical bias, what approach should i use to deal with this dilemma? from what i learnt, nonparametric methods are the most suiteable for small size samples, but how do i know which nonparametric method is the best?
the null hypothesis mean would be = or ≠ 0

Comment: "my mentor told me that using t-test on a sample with less than 30 data would cause a statistical bias" --  there's no reason that a small sample size would of itself cause bias. The t-test is designed to work 'as advertised' with samples of any size sufficient to estimate the variances. The only issue with small samples may be low power (which is not a bias).  It's not quite clear what issue your mentor may have been thinking of (there may be other reasons (besides power) to be concerned about small samples, but none of them relate specifically to n=30.

Comment: How about letting us see the data: Preferably, with each group typed in a row, with observations separated by commas. Then maybe someone can see if data are suitable for t test, Wilcoxon test, or something else.

Comment: Perhaps see [Answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405489/accuracy-vs-precision-can-i-use-the-sphercity-assumption-data-in-a-meaningful-w/405543#405543) to somewhat similar Question.